# i have used before_filter :authenticate_user! in my controller and how can i get the data as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have used before_filter :authenticate_user! in my controller and if i remove it and give

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X GET http://localhost:3000/posts`

then i see json data. So how can i use the before_filter :authenticate_user! so as to make it secure.

Comment: Did not really understand your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want json for iphone app and i use  devise as authentication and after logging in i want json from posts controller. how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Basic Authentiation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) for JSON requests, so auth crdentials could be included in http headers.